# How to open a saved model, remove all epochs saved but the best one and save it again?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

My model was saved with `save-strategy='epochs'` and now the `.bin` file is really big.  Is there a way to load it and remove all checkpoins from it but the best one and save it again to make it smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Within your training loop, you can keep track of your model's best validation value(s) and override your checkpoint each time the model improves in performance. This way you reduce the size by only keeping the best checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong. Huggingface does not save multiple checkpoints into a single bin file. That bin file actually originates from pytorch and it is a single model.

So your bin file contains a single model, you cant open it remove all epochs or whatsoever.

If you want to take the last model, use the `TrainingArguments`.

> load_best_model_at_end (bool, optional, defaults to False) — Whether
> or not to load the best model found during training at the end of
> training. When set to True, the parameters save_strategy needs to be
> the same as evaluation_strategy, and in the case it is “steps”,
> save_steps must be a round multiple of eval_steps.

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.load_best_model_at_end

and save your model at the end of the training.